# parsing microdata with Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, schema.org, microdata

Does anyone have any experience with using Google Apps Script to extract schema.org's microdata from a website with GScrip. I'm trying to write a GScript that will fetch back the microdata so that I can use it in sheets and hitting various problems.
Any existing libraries/code examples anyone aware of?

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far, what is the result your are expecting and what problems exactly did you encounter?

Comment: The same question is on the Apps Script G+ forum: https://plus.google.com/+AndrewRoberts1/posts/Rb5RqdEpunG?sfc=true. Few more details there.

Comment: The main issue I have is trying to do the microdata parsing on the server, rather than client side. There is a nice library in the Microdata.reveal chrome extension (https://github.com/jcdarwin/microdata.reveal) but this is very reliant on jQuery which I imagine would be hard to get running or find alternative functionality.
I’ve tried a few Apps Script HTML parsers like (https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html) and (http://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html) but it isn’t very hard to find a web page that they fail on.